# Sort Eloquent collection by a certain rule

Tags: php, sorting, eloquent, laravel-5

I have a table in my database named `users` and I have created a model `User`. Every user in my database has a certain `latitude` and `longitude`. So, I want to sort the users based on their location. An example of this would be:
Let's say one of my user has latitude 34.567 and longitude 56.983. Now, I want to display all the users whose latitude and longitude is very near to that of mine. Let's say: 34.975 and 56.884. So, I want to display that particular users whose location is near to the location of my user. So, how do I do that sorting stuff in Laravel.

> Note: Yes, there is no code with the question. But, I have searched in the documentation for something like this but, they have documentation for particular cases like `sorting on the basis of posted time and so on.` Thanks.

Comment: Doing this in PHP isn't the best approach. Some relational databases support geospatial queries, so you can get items ordered by how close they are to a certain point. PostgreSQL supports this via the PostGIS extension and I believe it's also supported in newer releases of MySQL and MariaDB. If you aren't using a relational database, MongoDB also supports this out of the box, and I think CouchDB may too.

Answer (score 0):

Fairly generic PHP code for sorting via distance:

```
// Get the requested latitude and longitude (from whatever source)
$lat = $coords['latitude'];
$lng = $coords['longitude'];
$distance = 81; // Radius of distance in kilometers

$earthRadius = 6731; // accepted mean radius of the Earth in kilometres

if ($distance == 0) {
    $distance = 81; // Default to 50 miles (in km) if no distance given!
}

$latDistance = $distance / 111.325;
$lngDistance = (cos(abs($lat)) * $distance) / 111.325;
$minLat = $lat - $latDistance;
$maxLat = $lat + $latDistance;
$minLng = $lng - $lngDistance;
$maxLng = $lng + $lngDistance;

$boundaryCalculation = "(users.latitude >= {$minLat} AND users.latitude <= {$maxLat} AND users.longitude >= {$minLng} AND users.longitude <= {$maxLng})";

$distanceCalculation = "(ACOS(SIN({$lat}*PI()/180) * SIN(users.latitude*PI()/180) + (COS({$lat}*PI()/180)*COS(users.latitude*PI()/180) * COS((({$lng}-users.longitude)*PI()/180)))) * {$earthRadius})";

// Create the query
// Note, should be parameterized but this gives the idea
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE " . $boundaryCalculation . " AND " . $distanceCalculation;
```

This gives a good introduction: https://www.scribd.com/presentation/2569355/Geo-Distance-Search-with-MySQL

Note that from version 5.7 MySQL provides a built-in function for calculating the distance between two points on a sphere. Might be of use!

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-convenience-functions.html

Comment: Will you please tell what it does step by step. And, is the query at last complete? Thanks for your time.

Comment: Last query should be complete but you might need to customise based on your table and requirements (e.g. find only authenticated users or those who have stated that you can track their position!).